# Microphone monitoring disabled, low volume (Blue Yeti USB, Ubuntu 20.04) [SOLVED]

Tags: sound, microphone

I have been using a Blue Yeti USB Mic under Ubuntu 20.04. It was working great. Then, it suddenly started having issues. I'm not sure when it started. It took a while for me to notice.

The mic will pick up sound, but the volume is not as high as it used to be and I can't seem to increase it. The bigger issue, however, is that the monitoring isn't working. That is, I can't hear myself through the headphones that are connected to the mic. I'm currently more concerned about the monitoring.

The mic itself is OK. It works fine under Windows 10. When I reboot to Ubuntu, monitoring also works for a few seconds and then cuts off.

The mic shows up in the input options. I've tried every input version. I've also checked in pavucontrol and tried every setting I could there. The monitoring shows up as an option (if that is what monitoring is in pavucontrol), but I can't change anything (it is not muted).

I'm a Ubuntu sound noob.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

After much searching, I ran alsamixer. The mic gain was 0. No idea how that happened. I never changed it. Once it was increased, the monitoring starting working again.

The capture was also low. I upped it. That helped with the mic recording volume.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I can confirm that running `alsamixer` and selecting (with F6) the sound card  **Yeti Stereo Microphone** and increasing the volumes fixed this.
My gain configurations: **Speaker -8.0dB, Mic +0.0dB, Capture +6.0dB**